# LAMP: Is there any way to see the SQL clauses that have been executed in a request?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, lamp

using LAMP, is there any way to see the SQL clauses that have been executed in a request?

Regards

Javi

Comment: LAMP is not an app, it is just a combination of applications.  You only need the 'M' to accomplish what you need. MySQL logging

Comment: are you know where the mysql logs are?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MySQL query log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you can't look at mysql's query log, you can extend mysqli or pdo, or simply wrap mysql_query in a custom function:

```
function my_mysql_query($sql, $link = null)
{
  echo "<div class="sql_query">SQL: ", htmlspecialchars($sql, ENT_COMPAT), "</div>\n";
  return mysql_query($sql, $link);
}
```

You have the option to echo the sql, save it to a logfile, database, whatever, based on whatever (debug constants, ...)